# JSON Data for Highcharts in Symfony2 with ObHighchartsBundle

Tags: json, symfony, highcharts

I use the ObHighchartsBundle for the Highcharts-Support in Symfony2. So far as long as I have an defined (php-) array with data everything works fine.

But I want so use json-data (e.g. in a file) - how can i realize this?

Thanks in advance

**Controller-Class:**

```
public function chartAction()
{
            $series = array(
            array(
                "name" => "Input",
                "data" => $this->getArray()
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Output",
                "data" => $this->getArray())
        );

        $ob->chart->renderTo('datachart');  // The #id of the div where to render the chart
        $ob->chart->backgroundColor('transparent');
        $ob->title->text("Hello Title");

        $ob->xAxis->type('datetime');
        $ob->chart->zoomType("x");

        $ob->xAxis->title(array('text' => "Horizontal axis title"));
        $ob->yAxis->title(array('text' => "Vertical axis title"));
        $ob->series($series);

        return $this->render(':charts:charts.html.twig', array(
            'chart' => $ob
        ));
}
```

**HTML-Twig:**

```
{% block head %}
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {{ chart(chart) }}
    </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div id="datachart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the solution:

**HTML.Twig:**

```
script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-v.json&callback=?', function (data) {
            {{ chart(chart, false) }}
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
$ob->series(array(
            array('data' => new \Zend\Json\Expr('data'))
        ));
```